# Use String to Read Config File Variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, configuration-files

I have a config file (leaderboard.json) that looks like this:

```
{
    "usercount<@386679122614681600>": 0
}
```

I am trying to read the value of that variable (so it would be 0) in my index.js file which looks like this:

```
var LEADERBOARD = require('./leaderboard.json');
const usercount = 'usercount'+user
var countvalue = LEADERBOARD.usercount
console.log(countvalue)
```

I essentially want countvalue to return 0 but I can't simply use LEADERBOARD.usercount<@386679122614681600> since that name will be changing.

Basically, I'm wondering whether there is a workaround to where I can read my config file variable using a string I create.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) for that.

`var countvalue = LEADERBOARD[usercount]`

Here's an example:

```js
const foo = {
  bar123: 'baz'
}

const prop = 'bar' + 123
console.log(foo[prop])
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `[]` notation.

because for `.` notation property must be a valid JS identifier [Read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Dot_notation).

> property must be a valid JavaScript identifier, i.e. a sequence of alphanumerical characters, also including the underscore ("_") and dollar sign ("$"), that cannot start with a number. For example, object.$1 is valid, while object.1 is not.

```js
let obj = {
    "usercount<@386679122614681600>": 0
}

const count = `386679122614681600`;
const useCount = `usercount<@${count}>`;

console.log(obj[useCount])
```

Answer (score -1):

Using a *string you create* you can return the value of the user account.

```
const LEADERBOARD = {
    "usercount<@386679122614681600>": 0
}

// String you create
const userId = '386679122614681600'
const userCount = `usercount<@${userId}>`

console.log(LEADERBOARD[userCount]) // 0
```

Answer (score -1):

This answer will help you if you know you are only accessing the first element! There isn't any more information on that so I will assume it's a potential answer:

You can use Object.keys to put the value into array format and then access the first value with [0] and it will return the 0 value.

```js
var obj = {
    "usercount<@386679122614681600>": 0
}

var countvalue = obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]];

console.log(countvalue)
```

I really hope this helps. Please let me know if this wasn't your requirement.